# Understanding QuantumEspresso Toolbox through Maestro

Tags: software, quantum-espresso, high-performance-computing, geometry-optimization, schrodinger-software

Anyone here uses Quantum Espresso through Maestro can tell me a bit more about the calculation panel setting:

[image]

I understand that `-npools` option must be divisible by the number of processors (threads). But I don't really understand the `-ntg` option. I am running some geometry optimization with $4 \times 4 \times 1$ kpoints but certain setting cause the calculation to fail. The job will get submitted, but I would get back an error like:

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

     stopping ...

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     Error in routine divide_et_impera (1):
     some nodes have no k-points
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Does `-ntg` depend on the number of kpoints you use? And if you can also tell me how much more the `simultaneous jobs` options speed up the calculation then that would be greatly appreciated! I have tried to increase the `simultaneous jobs` but it doesn't seems to really speed up the calculation... maybe it has to do with how I specified other paramters (-npool, -ntg, etc. )

I am trying to find the best way to speed-up the calculation, but so far it has been trials and errors. I would like to understand this setting more, and know how to speed-up my calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MAESTRO help system we got that the calculation is run using the driver **periodic_dft_driver.py**:

```
usage: $SCHRODINGER/run periodic_dft_gui_dir/periodic_dft_driver.py
       [-h] -cfg_file CFG_FILE [-TPP THREADS] [-nimage NIMAGE]
       [-npools NPOOLS] [-ntg NTG | -nband NBAND] [-qargs QARGS]
       [-HOST <hostname>]
       input_file

Driver that runs Quantum ESPRESSO workflows. Copyright Schrodinger, LLC. All
rights reserved.

positional arguments:
  input_file          Input structures.

optional arguments:
  -h, -help           Show this help message and exit.
  -cfg_file CFG_FILE  Path to the config file. (default: None)
  -TPP THREADS        Number of threads to use for each job. (default: 1)
  -qargs QARGS        Set arguments to pass to the queue manager. (default:
                      None)

Quantum ESPRESSO parallel options:
  -nimage NIMAGE      Number of images (points in the configuration space)
                      (default: 1)
  -npools NPOOLS      Number of K-point groups to run in parallel (default: 1)
  -ntg NTG            Number of task groups to run in parallel (default: None)
  -nband NBAND        Number of bands to run in parallel (default: None)

Job Control Options:
  -HOST <hostname>    Run job remotely on the indicated host entry. (default:
                      localhost)
```

Look for slides 10-21 for parallel options in [this](https://materials.prace-ri.eu/497/7/QE__main_strategies_of_parallelization_and_levels_of_parallelisms.pdf) document.

#### About k-points and $n_{pools}$:

> **k-point parallelization**
>
> If the simulation consists in different k-points, those can be distributed among $n_{pools}$ pools of CPUs.
>
> K-points are typically independents: the amount of communications is small
>
> When there is a large number of k-points this layer can strongly enhance
> the scalability
>
> By definition, $n_{pools}$ must be a divisor of the total
> number of k-points:
>
> `mpirun –np 64 pw.x –npool 4 –input inputfile.inp`

#### About task-group parallelization and $ntg$

> Each plane-wave group of processors is split into $n_{task}$ task groups of $n_{FFT}$ processors, with $n_{task} \times n_{FFT}= n_{PW}$;
>
> each task group takes care of the FFT over $N_e/n_t$ states.
>
> Used to extend scalability of FFT parallelization.
>
> Example for 1024 processors
> –divided into $n_{pool}= 4$ pools of $n_{PW} = 256$ processors,
> –divided into $n_{task} = 8$ tasks of $n_{FFT} = 32$ processors each;
> –Subspace diagonalization performed on a subgroup of $n_{diag} = 144$ processors:
>
> `mpirun –np 1024 pw.x –npool 4 –ntg 8 –ndiag 144 –input inputfile.inp`

About speeding up your calculations, the last 4 slides are about the QE scalability and [this](http://www.max-centre.eu/codes-max/quantum-espresso) link can help.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much @Camps.